# Как запустить команды WP-CLI в разных потоках?

Tags: php, wordpress, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Хочу создать команду, которая будет включать в себя несколько кастомных команд WP-CLI которые будут запускаться в разных потоках. Много читал за многопоточность в php,но именно как ето реализовать с WP-CLI для WordPress, не нашел. Возможно, кто-то пробовал сделать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать многопоточность в php, вам нужен thread safe дистрибутив.  Вряд ли он установлен на вашем сервере.

WP-CLI сама по себе не поддерживает многопоточность, в коде нет никаких намёков на это. Так что весьма вероятно, что вы столкнётесь с многочисленными проблемами при попытке запуска WP-CLI в нескольких потоках.

Лучше запускать эти команды асинхронно в фоне средствами bash:

```
wp do-something1 &
wp do-something2 &
```